# Traveling to Australia, can I visit Malaysia without a visa?

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens, malaysia

I already got my student visa from Australia and I would like to ask a question here.

I am Pakistani national .Is it possible to enter/visit Malaysia without a visa?

Comment: @fahadabbas what is your nationality?

Comment: I am Pakistani passport

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Yes (Pakistan, India, Bangladesh and Sri Lanka) nationals  holders of
>   a valid visa issued by Australia, China (People's  Rep.), Chinese
>   Taipei, Japan, Korea (Rep.), New Zealand or  USA are entitled to stay
>   in Kuala Lumpur (Malaysia) only for a maximum of 120 hours provided
>   they have transit time longer than 8 hours in KL

**Conditions**:

> Entry permitted only in Kuala Lumpur with confirmed onward ticket  on
>   Malaysian Airlines and Airasia with transit time more than 8 hours and
>   less than 120 hours. Also passport should be valid for at least 6
>   months from the date of arrival.

Source : [Visa Information](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The rules here seem to limit the applicability severely: only during a stopover of 8+ hours in length, max time of 120 hours, must be traveling to/from Australia, passport valid for 6 months, and must be traveling on a packaged tour purchased from a company registered in Australia (unless simply going between terminals). It is, of course, possible to meet all these conditions, but they exclude many such possible trips the OP may be planning.

Comment: @zach Lipton check update embarkation, transit and destination result